# difficulty giving aliases inside case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is giving me the output as shown in the screenshot below.

```
select 
    a.storeId, b.district, b.region,
    count (case when a.photoAppImage is null then 1 end) as via_u,
    count (case when a.photoAppImage =1 then 1 end) as via_p
from 
    used_listings_V2 a
left outer join 
    locations b on a.storeId = b.storeID 
where 
    convert(date, a.imageUpdateDate) = convert(date, GETDATE()-1)
group by 
    a.storeId, b.district, b.region
```

edited

I wanted to split the counts in two different columns that I am getting in a single row. All the records having null photoAppImage should have the count displayed under “Via_u” and the records having 1 photoAppImage should have the count displayed under “Via_p”. The expected output will look this:

Basically I think I am having difficulty giving aliases inside case statement. Can somebody please help me on this?

Comment: Please post your code and data as text, not images

Comment: Bad habbits to kick: [using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Count(case when a.photoappimage is null then 1 end) as via_u,
Count(case when a.photoappimage is null then 1 end)/100. as via_u_pct,
Count(case when a.photoappimage=1 then 1 end ) as via_p,
Count(case when a.photoAppImage is null or a.photoAppImage=1 then 1 end) as via_u_or_p
```

Update: combining all (and use a subquery to simplify pct calculation):

```
select 
    storeId, 
    district,
    region,
    via_u,
    via_p,
    via_u/100./(via_u+via_p) as via_u_pct
from (
    select 
        a.storeId, b.district, b.region,
        count (case when a.photoAppImage is null then 1 end) as via_u,
        count (case when a.photoAppImage =1 then 1 end) as via_p
    from 
        used_listings_V2 a
    left outer join 
        locations b on a.storeId = b.storeID 
    where 
        convert(date, a.imageUpdateDate) = convert(date, GETDATE()-1)
    group by 
        a.storeId, b.district, b.region
    ) Step1
```

Comment: its not giving correct output.  StoreId 111 should appear only once in the output

Comment: You should also remove photoappimage from the select and the group by. You can't both show that and expect one row. If you want people edit your query please don't expect to re-type the whole thing

Comment: But you group by multiple columns - making your goal inconsistent with your query and your description. No one can read your mind nor your schema. Perhaps remove a.photoAppImage from your GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @tinazmu thank you so much! Its working as expected.  I have removed the image and added code in the question. Also, I wanted to add two count columns i.e. via_u and via_p but I am not able to do so since they are aliases I guess. Any way to achieve that ?

Comment: @SMor  If I remove district and region from the group by, I cannot select those fields and I want that in the output. What can I do in that case. Sorry I know its a stupid question but I'm very new to SQL

Comment: Isn't your latest edit giving you what you want (with store_id, district, region in the SELECT and in GROUP BY)? We only suggested removing photoAppImage, not the others.

Comment: Yes @tinazmu. Its giving correct output.

Comment: Can you help me in adding values of via_u and via_p.  for example for the first row addition (an extra column needed in the output) should hold 4 (4+0)

Comment: Do you mean having, in addition to via_u and via_p column, you want a count of these two, as well? you could do count(case when a.photoAppImage is null or a.photoAppImage=1 then 1 end)

Comment: Great @tinazmu. Tons of thanks to you. Its working as expected.  One last thing what if I wanted to calculate percentage like (via_u/addition)*100?????

Comment: Added the percentage example; choose as accepted answer if it did work

Comment: Hold on a second! what is 'addition'? where does it come from?

Comment: addition is via_u_or_p